# Stripe OAuth with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow this documentation from Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

I'm stuck on point 4 where I am trying to authorize a user and get a response with an access token.

I am using a express backend in a React app and I have the following set up in my server.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');

var TOKEN_URI = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';
var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx'
var API_KEY = 'STRIPE_API_KEY'

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('/api/callback', function(req, res) {

    var code = req.query.code;

    request.post({
      url: TOKEN_URI,
      form: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        code: code,
        client_secret: API_KEY
      }
    }, function(err, r, body) {

      var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
      console.log(accessToken);

    });
  });

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
```

I've removed my port number and listening reference but this is in place.

So when I test with Stripe and go my callback page I get an Internal Server Error but I am not sure what is causing this and why I am getting no response back from my console.log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to import the request library at the top 
const request = require('request');
Also please make sure your package.json file contains request library if not please install it first. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: I added request and this has solved my issue. Thankyou so much.